# Kubernetes connection refused although service is exposed as NodePort

Tags: angular, kubernetes, vagrant

I have an angular server running on kubernetes. If I do

```
kubectl logs angular-pod-8d5586f44-q2jz3,
```

I get, at the bottom, the well known

```
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

Additionally, I have also exposed the service as a NodePort on port 4200, as following lines prove:

```
angular-client    NodePort    10.102.59.116    <none>        4200:32396/TCP   6s.
```

However, I get a connection refused error when I try

```
curl 10.102.59.116:4200
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.102.59.116 port 4200: Connection refused.
```

Has anyone also encountered this problem and know how to fix it ?

By the way, I am using vagrant with virtualbox as vm-machine.

Comment: Does `curl 10.102.59.116:32396` work? Seems 32396 is the port being exposed.

Comment: You are talking about " angular server", but you state shows "angular-client".

Comment: To the first comment: It does not work, although it doesn't give me the error mentioned above, but is just stalled. In any case, that is the inner cluster IP address, so it should work with port 4200, if I understand inner cluster communication well.

Comment: Regarding the second comment: What I mean by angular server is that ng serve is carried out with the result of the server being up, as is shown by the Compiled Successfully output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using angular-cli, you would have to run `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` in order for angular cli to expose the angular-life-server.
However it is **not** recommended to do this for production purposes, as the angular-life server is not fully reviewed for security concerns, but only meant as a development tool. To deploy you angular app for production, it would be best to do a production build (`ng build --prod`) and deploy the result inside e.g. a nginx-container.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. However, it does not really answer the question, as my problem is rather why it is not working, given that it worked on minikube.

Comment: From where are you running the curl? The kubernetes service will only be reachable from within the cluster.